AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'
I've followed all steps of that SO answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78926745/803195) but when I authenticate the account, the following exception is throwed:

Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: (...) AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret' (...)

I've setup all parameters correctly and the Azure app is allowing public client flows as is mentioned in some response about that exception.

Could you include Authentication tab image of your app registration by editing your question?

Ouch! When I print the screen, I've seen that the redirect uri was only in the Web section, not in the Mobile and Desktop applications. Now it's working! Thanks!

The error occurs if you add redirect URI in Web platform which won't work while using interactive flows as you enabled public client flow option.
To resolve the error, make sure to remove the redirect URI in Web platform  and make sure to add it in Mobile and desktop applications  platform as below:


Ah! When testing locally -- e.g. In Visual Studio with local host, you're a "Mobile or Desktop" app.  When running in Production, you're a "Web" app.   Thanks Sridevi
